# AEM - implications of using admin session

Tags: session, aem

This one code snippet is what i've been seeing many times nowadays.

```
  Session adminSession = slingRepository.loginAdministrative(null);
  session = adminSession.impersonate (new SimpleCredentials("author",new char[0]));
  adminSession.logout();
```

and then, using `session` object for further processing.
Now, for sure there must be some implications of using an admin session, but i ain't precisely sure what those are.
So, my question is

### 1. What are implications of using an Admin Session in case of any specific user's Session?

### 2. What Admin's session is for?(must be some use case when admin session is required)

EDIT:
i believe using an adminResourceResolver also have the same implications. Just to be sure

### 3. When to and when not to use admin's `resourceResolver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What are implications of using an Admin Session in case of any specific user's Session?

It's very simple, you are short circuiting AEM's security model. This is extremely bad to do as you allow users in certain functions to potentially operate under higher access priviliges.

2. What Admin's session is for?(must be some use case when admin session is required)

The admin user session actually should never be used. It can be used to perform automated system functions, and there may be circumstances where the function provides the appropriate security controls, however, the better approach is to use an assigned user with a set of access rights to loft to under these circumstances.

3. When to and when not to use admin's resourceResolver?

The best practice answer. Never.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining admin session via the mentioned snippet is most used anti pattern in cq 5.6 and its predecessor.

The session obtained this way gives you complete accesss to the repository and you can virtually do anything good/**bad**.

To handle this starting 6.0 sessions needs to be obtained per service, and relative permission needs to be given for them.

Check following link [sling service authentication](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/service-authentication.html) for more understanding.